# Multiple SUM and JOIN on mysql with one query

Tags: mysql, join, sum

I have a table :

```
    member [member_id,member_name]
```

and my other table is :

```
  balance [balance_id,member_id,balance(transaction)]
```

and now i have join these tables and add SUM(balance) for where member_id is same!
EXAMPLE :

member:

```
member_id , member_name
1, test_1
2, test_2
```

balance

```
balance_id,member_id,balance
1,1,-800
2,1,1000
3,2,500
```

member join balance

```
member_id , balance
1,200
2,500
```

NOTICE : I have all of this with one query!

Comment: Do you have a question?  You should include sample data, desired results, and an actual question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff actually my question is : how use multiple sum on one table (on one column). and I added a sample to question very simple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your expected output, this will do:

```
select member_id,
    sum(balance) balance
from balance
group by member_id
```

if you need to join it with the member table, do:

```
select m.*,
    b.balance
from member m
join (
    select member_id,
        sum(balance) balance
    from balance
    group by member_id
    ) b on m.member_id = b.member_id;
```

Another way is to join first and then do aggregation:

```
select m.member_id,
    m.member_name,
    sum(b.balance) balance
from member m
join balance b on m.member_id = b.member_id
group by m.member_id,
    m.member_name;
```

Comment: actually I need to join! for some reason. your second code is true but is not one query!

Comment: @user6935676 - it *is* one query. Does it not do what you want?

Comment: @user6935676 - Added a third one. Please check